# JQuery slideshow : Firefox v.13.0.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am using the following script for slideshow gallery, it should rotate a few pics one after the other each 10 seconds.

It worked  ( in FF) until I upgraded Firefox to version 13.0.1.

At the moment, if it runs for a while, then it gets messed up -  it neglects the timer,  rotates only 2 pics, and completely neglects the other 3.

How can I fix this issue and  make the script more robust?

Thank you!!!

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow div.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow div:last');

    //  pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow div:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    var timer = setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 10000 );

        $('#slideshow').hover(
                function () {
                    clearInterval(timer);   
                },  
                function () {
                    timer = setInterval("slideSwitch()", 10000);            
                }
        ); 

});
```

I call the jquery in html via:

```
                    <div id="slideshow">
                        <div class="active">
                            <img src="/images/slideImages/1.jpg" alt="xxx 1" title = "xx 1"/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="/images/slideImages/2.jpg" alt="xxx 2" title="xx 2" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="/images/slideImages/3.jpg"  alt="xxx 3" title="xx 3" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="/images/slideImages/4.jpg"  alt="xx 4" title="xx 4"  />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="/images/slideImages/5.jpg"  alt="xxx 5" title="xx 5"  />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your tag type is "javascript"

Firefox doesn't understand "jscript"  like chrome and safari do

Comment: It was "Javascript" already, although the charset was "utf-8 without BOM". I am wondering if this might be the issue. Changed it to "utf8" only. Thanks.